# Is writing an IE addon harder than writing one for Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

The number of IE addons seems to be far lower than Firefox and Chrome extensions - why's that? Is it much harder to write one? Are there particular barriers?

Comment: Hard is a subjective term. However extensions were supported by the other other browsers a lot earlier than IE so that can explain there are fewer for IE.

Comment: @PreetSangha: Excuse me? Internet Explorer extensions have been around [since IE5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that's before Firefox or Chrome even existed. What was introduced recently is merely a webpage listing these extensions.

Comment: Really? I had no idea.....I stand corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, creating IE extensions is much harder and requires a lot more knowledge, that's a very old mechanism going back to the browser wars era. You have to use ActiveX (typically one would write an extension in C++), communicate with the browser via COM interfaces, create an installer that will install the extension on disk and register it. All kinds of low-level stuff. On the other hand, Firefox and Chrome extensions are written in JavaScript, use high-level APIs (in Chrome more high-level than in Firefox) and only need to be packed up, the browser will install them itself.

For reference:

- [Internet Explorer extensions documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Getting started tutorial for Mozilla's Add-on SDK extensions](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/tutorial/)
- [Getting started tutorial for Google Chrome extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)